# How to say this proof correctly: if $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$ then $d\mid (a-b)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I believe I have this proof solved, but not sure that I wrote it correctly.

Given that $d|a$ then there exist a $n$ such that $n = dk$ for some $k$
Given that $d|b$ then there exist a $m$ such that $m = dj$ for some $j$
where $d,a,n,j,k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Then $d|a-b \rightarrow d|dk-dj \rightarrow d|d(k-j)$

This is where I don't know what to say.

Edit: Thanks to Prahlad Vaidyanathan, etc all.

If $d|a$, then there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nd = a$, Similarly, $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $md = b$ By the Distributive Law $(n-m)d = a-b$.

IS this it? Thought there would be more words.

Comment: No. If $d\mid a$, then there is $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nd = a$. Similarly, $\exists m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $md = b$. Now $(n-m)d = a-b$

Comment: A slightly more meta point, to help you identify such mistakes in future - you interpreted "$d|a$" as "there exists $n$ such that $n=dk$ for some $k$", but this second statement doesn't have an $a$ in it...

Comment: Good point, Matt.  It should read that Given that $d|a,$ then there exists an integer $k$ such that $a=dk$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Is your comment the entire proof?  I understand my statement are not right.

Comment: yiyi, yes, the one-liner by P.V. is a complete proof, and it is done directly from definition of $a|b$. As for your "I don't know what to say": Every number $d$ divides all multiples of itself, by definition ;)

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Could you consider making that into an answer? It seems that it wound up being the best solution for the user in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The first attempt is incorrect. The second attempt appears correct. A concise proof would be as follows:

By definition,
\begin{align*}
d \mid a & \Longleftrightarrow a = dm \text{ for some } m \\
d \mid b & \Longleftrightarrow b = dn \text{ for some } n \\
\end{align*}

then
$$a - b = dm - dn =  d(m - n) \Longrightarrow d \mid (a - b).$$